# unsigned char array incompatible with pointer parameter

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this function

```
unsigned char NCN_System_upload(unsigned char *data, unsigned char len);
```

I have an array defined as such:

```
unsigned char data[3];
```

I'm using the function as the following:

```
NCN_System_upload(&data, 3);
```

However, I get the following error:

> argument of type `unsigned char (*)[3]` is incompatible with parameter of type `unsigned char*`

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Arrays naturally decays to pointers, so no need for the address-of operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the array is already (can be implicitly converted) to a pointer to its beginning. Thus, you should do it like this:

```
NCN_System_upload(data, 3);
```

Comment: I knew I was being super dumb. Thanks!

Comment: The official wording would be *the name of the array already **decays** to a pointer...*. Arrays do not always act the same as pointers.

Comment: Actually, "decays" is an informal description as well (albeit one a lot of people seem to use).   The description in the standard - bearing in mind that the purpose of the standard is to be the definitive specification - is that "An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the first element of the array."     This is a long-winded way of describing an implicit conversion.   The word "decay" (or variants) does not even appear in the standards.